# Ms Sql Trigger Permission

Tags: sql-server

This trigger was not written by me or used with a stored proc original I modified it for my use. The problem to me appears to be one of permissions when the table is manually updated or inserted inSQL Server Management Studio the trigger works perfectly. When the Trigger is updated or inserted by a Stored Proc ran via an ODBC connection it does not modify the table and the Trigger does not work. If the trigger is disabled the stored Proc works as expected. So the error appers to be some form of permission error. Here is the trigger. (Using 2012)
Thanks In Advance
Donald S. Bossen

```
USE [JBI]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[send_ship_exec_info_to_p21]    Script Date: 8/29/2018 3:22:26 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[send_ship_exec_info_to_p21] ON [dbo].[ship_exec] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

declare @pick_ticket_no varchar(50)
declare @tracking_no varchar(50)
declare @pickup_date varchar(50)
declare @carrier_id varchar(50)
declare @package_count varchar(50)
declare @delete_flag varchar(50)
declare @package_weight varchar(50)
declare @package_charge decimal(9,4)
declare @total_shipment_charge decimal(19,4)
declare @carrier_name varchar(50)
declare @customer_freight_charge decimal(9,4)
declare @saturday_delivery varchar(50)
declare @transaction_type varchar(50)
declare @billing_option varchar(3)
select

    @pick_ticket_no = i.pick_ticket_no,
    @tracking_no = i.tracking_no,
    @pickup_date = i.pickup_date,--left(i.pickup_date,8),
    @carrier_id = i.service_type,
    @package_count = i.package_count,
    @delete_flag = i.delete_flag,
    @package_weight = i.package_weight,
    @package_charge = i.package_charge,
    @total_shipment_charge = i.total_shipping_and_handling_charge,
    @saturday_delivery = i.saturday_delivery,
    @transaction_type = i.transaction_type,
    @billing_option = i.billing_option
from inserted i

if @transaction_type = 'Inv Return'
begin
    declare @document_link_uid int
    declare @document_link_area_uid int
    declare @link_name varchar(255)
    declare @link_path varchar(4099)

    set @link_name = 'UPS shipment ' + cast(@pick_ticket_no as varchar(40)) + ': ' + @tracking_no
    set @link_path =  'http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion=5.0&sort_by=status&term_warn=yes&tracknums_displayed=5&TypeOfInquiryNumber=T&loc=en_US&InquiryNumber1=' + @tracking_no + '&InquiryNumber2=&InquiryNumber3=&InquiryNumber4=&InquiryNumber5=&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes&track.x=28&track.y=2'

    if @delete_flag = 'Y'
    begin
        update
            PROPHET21.dbo.document_link
        set
            row_status_flag = '700'
            ,date_last_modified = getdate()
            ,last_maintained_by = 'Ship Exec Delete Flag'
        where
            key1_cd = 'return_number'
            and key1_value = @pick_ticket_no
            and link_path like '%' + @tracking_no + '%'
    end

    if @delete_flag = 'N'
    begin
        if not exists(select document_link_uid from PROPHET21.dbo.document_link where link_path like '%' + @tracking_no + '%')
        begin
            exec @document_link_uid = PROPHET21.dbo.p21_get_counter 'document_link', 1
            INSERT INTO
                PROPHET21.dbo.document_link
                    (
                    document_link_uid
                    ,source_area_cd
                    ,key1_cd
                    ,key1_value
                    ,link_name
                    ,link_path
                    ,row_status_flag
                    ,date_created
                    ,created_by
                    ,date_last_modified
                    ,last_maintained_by
                    ,outside_use_flag
                    ,mandatory_flag
                    )
                VALUES
                    (
                    @document_link_uid
                    ,1312
                    ,'return_number'
                    ,@pick_ticket_no
                    ,@link_name
                    ,@link_path
                    ,704
                    ,getdate()
                    ,'SHIP EXEC'
                    ,getdate()
                    ,'SHIP EXEC'
                    ,'N'
                    ,'N'
                    )

            exec @document_link_area_uid = PROPHET21.dbo.p21_get_counter 'document_link_area', 1
            INSERT INTO
                PROPHET21.dbo.document_link_area
                    (
                    document_link_area_uid
                    ,document_link_uid
                    ,display_area_cd
                    ,row_status_flag
                    ,date_created
                    ,created_by
                    ,date_last_modified
                    ,last_maintained_by
                    )
                VALUES
                    (
                    @document_link_area_uid
                    ,@document_link_uid
                    ,1312
                    ,704
                    ,getdate()
                    ,'SHIP EXEC'
                    ,getdate()
                    ,'SHIP EXEC'
                    )
        end
    end
end
if @transaction_type <> 'SWS' or not exists(select oe_pick_ticket.pick_ticket_no from PROPHET21.dbo.oe_pick_ticket oe_pick_ticket where oe_pick_ticket.pick_ticket_no = @pick_ticket_no)
return

if @transaction_type = 'SWS' and exists(select oe_pick_ticket.pick_ticket_no from PROPHET21.dbo.oe_pick_ticket oe_pick_ticket where oe_pick_ticket.pick_ticket_no = @pick_ticket_no)
begin
    if (@delete_flag = 'Y')
        begin
            declare @invoiced_already varchar (50)
            select @invoiced_already = oe_pick_ticket.invoice_no
            from PROPHET21.dbo.oe_pick_ticket oe_pick_ticket
            where pick_ticket_no = @pick_ticket_no
                if(@invoiced_already is null)
                begin
                    update PROPHET21.dbo.clippership_return_10004
                    set delete_flag = 'Y'
                    where tracking_no = @tracking_no

                    update PROPHET21.dbo.oe_pick_ticket
                    set freight_out = 0, date_last_modified = getdate(), last_maintained_by = 'Ship Exec void package'
                    where pick_ticket_no = @pick_ticket_no
                end
        return
        end

    if (@delete_flag = 'N')--@tracking_no like '1z%' and 
    Begin
        declare @customer_pays_outgoing_freight char(1)
        select
            @customer_pays_outgoing_freight = freight_code.outgoing_freight
        from
            PROPHET21.dbo.oe_pick_ticket oe_pick_ticket
            inner join PROPHET21.dbo.freight_code freight_code on oe_pick_ticket.freight_code_uid = freight_code.freight_code_uid and oe_pick_ticket.company_id = freight_code.company_id
        where
            oe_pick_ticket.pick_ticket_no = @pick_ticket_no

        select
             @carrier_name = carrier.name
        from
            PROPHET21.dbo.address carrier
        where
            carrier.id = @carrier_id

        select @customer_freight_charge =
            cast(case
                when @billing_option in ('REC', 'TP', 'CB') then 0
                when coalesce(@customer_pays_outgoing_freight, 'Y') = 'N' then 0
                else ((@total_shipment_charge) / @package_count)
            end as decimal(19,2))

        update PROPHET21.dbo.oe_pick_ticket
          set freight_out = isnull(freight_out, 0) + isnull(@customer_freight_charge, 0),
              carrier_id = @carrier_id,
              tracking_no = @tracking_no
        where pick_ticket_no = @pick_ticket_no

        insert into PROPHET21.dbo.clippership_return_10004
            (pick_ticket_no,
            tracking_no,
            package_weight,
            order_count,
            shipped_date,
            carrier_name,
            total_charge,
            processed_flag,
            delete_flag,
            date_created,
            date_last_modified,
            last_maintained_by,
            line_number)
        values
            (@pick_ticket_no,
            @tracking_no,
            @package_weight,
            @package_count,
            @pickup_date,
            @carrier_name,
            @customer_freight_charge,
            'N',
            'N',
            getdate(),
            getdate(),
            'SHIP EXEC',
            0)
    end

    return
End
```

Comment: Well, as you said - it is probably a permission error. But without the error msg it can be hard to find. Try running it under SSMS with same user ODBC connection is using and see what happens.

Comment: Does the stored proc insert or update more than one row in a single statement?  The trigger presumes that only a single row is being changed.

Comment: I do not set permissions my boss ran SSMS. and here is what he said.  The server principal "upsuser" is not able to access the database "PROPHET21" under the current security context.


I gave “upsuser” full access to all of the tables that it needs to either read from or update.

Comment: There is also an insert - maybe that's the problem? You can try changing security context for trigger: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135793/permissions-on-trigger-problem